# Is it possible to connect to other RabbitMQ nodes when one node is down?

Tags: rabbitmq

The environment I have consists of two separate servers, one each with RabbitMQ service application running.  They are correctly clustered and the queues are using mirroring correctly.

Node A is master

Node B is slave

My question is more specifically when Node A goes down but Service A is still up.  Node B and Service B are still up.  At this point, Node B is now promoted to master.  When an application connects to Node B it connects okay, of course.

`rabbitmqctl cluster_status` on Node B shows cluster is up with two nodes and Node B is running.  `rabbitmqctl cluster_status` on Node A shows node is down.  This is expected behavior.

**It is possible for an application to connect to Node A and be able to publish/pop queue items as normal?**

Comment: no its not possible to connect to a node if it is down. Are you looking for something more like how to keep connection alive ?

Comment: I was just confused as to what I was observing.  I saw that a few of my applications were connected to Node A even though it was down, able to send message to the queue, but no new connections could be made.

Comment: actually they don't keep connected if node is down. They just keep trying on a time interval to connect to a node they get disconnected or node is down.

Comment: that clarification helps, thank you